# Extending an EDT for a Yes/No enum

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I've created my yes/no EDT called IsSpecialCustomer. When I choose the `Extends` property of `NoYesId`, it triggers a database sync.

If I use the base enum `NoYes`, it won't trigger a sync.  Is there any reason to use the `NoYesId` EDT over the `NoYes` enum?

I understand why I would use it if I were extending `SalesQty` for example, but since `NoYes` is a low level enum, and you'll never add `Maybe` to that, can I use the enum and still be best practice?

Is there **any** reason to use the EDT `NoYesId` over the enum `NoYes`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a field derived from NoYes will make a drop down list with the two values.
Using NoYesId EDT, you'll have a checkbox.